# Symfony2 - Chain Providers

Tags: php, symfony

I have 2 different bundles with 2 different routes.

```
/example1
/example2
```

I am trying to do a chain provider for these 2 different route to have a single sign on. They both are using a single entity for the users. I look at the chain providers which require 2 entities to use (not 100% sure about that)

```
 providers:
      members:
        entity: { class: SampleUserBundle:Member }
      chain_provider:
        chain:
          providers: [members]

firewalls:
      member:
        provider: members
        pattern: ^/example1
        anonymous: ~
      root:
        provider: members
        pattern: ^/example2
        anonymous: ~
```

I'm trying to redirect a link from /example1 to /example2 without logging in again.
Appreciate anyone who can assist me in this new thing I'm learning. TIA!

Comment: That is the reason to make to different firewalls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a single firewall for both route patterns?

You only have to adjust your configuration regex pattern accordingly ...

```
firewalls:
    member:
        provider: members
        pattern: ^/(example1|example2)
        anonymous: ~
```